# How to store and retrieve integer using Android Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save an integer value and retrieve the value using a same button using shared preferences. 
To be more precise, when i click a button the value should be incremented(i++) and then it should be stored. When i close and open the application, it should retrieve the same value from where i left it. How do i do this?
I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
public class OnPreferenceManager {
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String startHour = "startHour";
private OnPreferenceManager() {}

private OnPreferenceManager(Context mContext) {
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    editor = prefs.edit();
}

public static OnPreferenceManager getInstance(Context mContext)
{
    OnPreferenceManager _app = null;
    if (_app == null)
        _app = new OnPreferenceManager(mContext);
    return _app;
}

public void setStartHour(int hour){
    editor.putInt(startHour, hour);
    editor.apply();

}
 public int getStartHour(){
    int selectionStart = prefs.getInt(startHour, -1);
    return selectionStart;
}
```

}

When you need to set integer just write as below

```
OnPreferenceManager.getInstance(this).setStartHour(theValueYouWantToStore);
```

And to retrieve write

```
OnPreferenceManager.getInstance(this).getStartHour()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences as below.

```
//To save integer value
 SharedPreferences preference = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putInt("YOU_KEY",you_int_value);
 editor.commit();

 //To retrieve integer value
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR_PREF_NAME", 0);
 int snowDensity = settings.getInt("YOU_KEY", 0); //0 is the default value
```

Comment: It's better to use `apply` as it is async.

Answer (score 0):

Check this gist https://gist.github.com/john1jan/b8cb536ca51a0b2aa1da4e81566869c4

I have created a Preference Utils class that will handle all the cases.

Its Easy to Use

Storing into preference

```
PrefUtils.saveToPrefs(getActivity(), PrefKeys.USER_INCOME, income);
```

Getting from preference

```
Double income = (Double) PrefUtils.getFromPrefs(getActivity(), PrefKeys.USER_INCOME, new Double(10));
```